# Name error in Python3 when name is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am in spyder trying to run a fairly simple python code (python 3.6.4), but when I run the code and use the input statements, it says the names are not defined, even though they should be.

```
#Module 4 project
#4/25/18
#Henry Degner
#This project is meant to determine whether or not certain people are qualified to go to an exclusive concert

#create function askAge, which will use an input statement and comparison operators to see if the user is old enough
def askAge():
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    if( age >= 18 ):
        ageReq = "true"
    elif( age < 18 ):
        ageReq = "false"
    else:
        print("Please print you're age with only numerical characters, in years")
        age = int(input("How old are you? "))
#create function askHearing, yes or no question to do you have sensitive hearing
def askHearing():
    hearing = str(input("Do you have sensitive hearing? "))
    if( str(hearing) == "yes","y" ):
        hearingReq = "do"
    elif( str(hearing) == "no","n"):
        hearingReq = "don't"
    else:
        print("Please type yes, or y, if you have sensitivehearing. If not, type no or n.")
        hearing = str(input("Do you have sensitive hearing? "))
#create function askTicket, yes or no question to do you have a ticket
def askTicket():
    ticket = str(input("Do you have a ticket for the concert? "))
    if( str(ticket) == "yes","y" ):
        ticketReq = "do"
    elif( str(ticket) == "no","n"):
        ticketReq = "don't"
    else:
        print("Please type yes if you have a ticket, or no if you don't.")
        ticketReq = str(input("Do you have a ticket for the concert"))
#create function askFun, yes or no question to are you willing to have an awesome time
def askFun():
    fun = str(input("Are you willing to have a great time?"))
    if( str(fun) == "yes","y"):
        funReq = "do"
    elif( str(fun) == "no","n" ):
        funReq = "don't"
    else:
        print("Please type 'yes' or 'no'")
        fun = str(input("Are you willing to have a great time?"))
#use def main():
def main():
#print situation, will ask some questions to see if you can attend concert
    print("Welcome to the Henry Degner Concert Venue! We have to ask you a few questions before we let you into the venue.")
#use askAge
    askAge()
#use askHearing
    askHearing()
#use askTicket
    askTicket()
#use askFun
    askFun()
#print user's answers
    print("You said you are " + age + " years old, you " + hearingReq + " have sensitive hearing, you " + ticketReq + " have a ticket, and you " + funReq + " want to have a great time!")
#use if-else statement, if all three conditions match requirements, print you can attend concert. If not, print you can't attend

#use main()
main()
```

the error outputs as

```
File "C:/Users/henry/Documents/Current Classes/Foundations of Programming/Module 4 project/Module 4 project script.py", line 60, in main
    print("You said you are " + age + " years old, you " + hearingReq + " have sensitive hearing, you " + ticketReq + " have a ticket, and you " + funReq + " want to have a great time!")

NameError: name 'age' is not defined
```

It also says that all of the other names in line 60 aren't defined. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read about [how scoping works in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules). You define `age` in the `askAge()` function, but once you leave that function the variable will not be available in `main()`.

Comment: Someone is about to learn about return values :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `NameError: name 'age' is not defined` because variables from different functions are not shared until you declare them global or you return them from one method to another.

Read more about **[Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)**

Just return value from function to main method.

**Returning value from method**

```
def askAge():
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    if( age >= 18 ):
        ageReq = "true"
    elif( age < 18 ):
        ageReq = "false"
    else:
        print("Please print you're age with only numerical characters, in years")
        age = int(input("How old are you? "))

    return age

def main():
    ...
    age = askAge()
    .....
```

Same you need to do it for all methods,

```
askHearing()
askTicket()
askFun()
```

Comment: No, you don't. Because assigning to it in the function will make it local, and that's just bad advice.

Comment: @Aran-Fey. I was just sitting there trying to figure out how to say that :)

Comment: Please don't even mention global variables. They're a horrible solution for this problem. Talking about global variables here is a waste of time at best, and a newbie trap at worst.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Declaring the variables as global worked. It seems that variables defined in user-defined functions need to be declared as global before they can be used in the def main(): statement or any other functions. Thank you guys for your help, and I'll be sure to try to find an answer to questions like these before I post them.

Comment: @user9705945 as per Aran-Fey suggested don't use global variable. Please consider accepting answer.